# How to access files on a docker app from different local locations

Tags: docker, user-input, mount

I am an absolute beginner with Docker, so any and all advice would be greatly appreciated.

I'm building a script that will require the user to specify the paths to files on their local drive. I'd like the user to be able to specify the paths of local files using flags for my script.

I know a little bit about mounting. This is what I've tried so far.

`docker run -i -v /path/to/files/locally:/mnt/mydata`

However, when I run my script, and try to specify the path to the files, they are only found under mnt/mydata/ and it doesn't seem like there is a way to specify the local disk location.

It's important that the user be able to specify the file path on the local drive because they may be in several different locations. Is there any way to do this? Or at least mount several different locations using the -v flag?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve, however you can mount as many volumes you want using multiple -v commands

Comment: As you've described the setup, it's not a good match for Docker (especially the very strong emphasis on local files).  It will be a better end-user experience if they can just run your script, without needing to learn the subleties of Docker volume mounts and the separated filesystem.